# Multithreaded producer consumer app on librdkafka

Tags: apache-kafka

Can multiple producers share shame copy of conf? 
If you can not share same copy of conf, is it ok to share same dr_cb ?

Answer (score 1):

The C API (`rd_kafka_new()`, `rd_kafka_topic_new()`) will take ownership of the passed `.._conf_t` object, so if you want to reuse it for another client or topic you will need to use the `.._conf_dup()` function to make a copy first.

The C++ factory constructors copies the provided `Conf` object automatically and does not take ownership of it.

You also mention multithreading: librdkafka is thread-safe and you can use the same producer or consumer client from multiple threads.

Comment: Thanks That was helpfull!